# CSS3 animation, stay put

Tags: jquery, css, translate-animation

I'm using the following animation:

```
.wheel1anim {
    -webkit-animation-name: wheel1go;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wheel1go {
    0% {
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 150px);
    }
}
```

The animation works fine, but once the animation is finished, the element moves from the place it was animated to, to its default position

Is there a way to make it stay in place?

Comment: -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; seems to have worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one line in .wheel1anim:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
```